# Socket.io Syntax not Recognized on Server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, server, socket.io

Node server not able to understand `socket.io` syntax, even with all packages installed.

When I run my server locally with `nodejs server.js` it works fine is working. But, when I try to run it on my Ubuntu server, it does not seem to understand this line:

```
socket.on( 'client-data', ( serverpackage ) => {
                                            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

The directory on my Ubuntu server is `user/server`, which contains all my server modules. `Socket.io` is installed, and I even checked to make sure all dependencies for `socket.io` are there too.

```
NodeJS-Socket-server-with-DB@1.0.0 /home/<user>/server
└── socket.io@2.1.1
```

I am also running this version of nodejs:

```
<user>@host*****:~/server$ nodejs -v
v0.10.25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use arrow functions. You need at minimum version 4 of node however version 6 offers full compatability with arrow functions.

To fix your issue simply update node or change to a regular function like:

```
socket.on( 'client-data', function (serverpackage) {
```

Comment: You shouldn't in my opinion, use function if you want, but the issue is you have a really outdated version of node, which is no longer supported, you should install the latest version, or a LTS one.

Comment: I do agree with @MarcosCasagrande updating Node would be a much better solution however I was providing an immediate fix to the users issue.

Comment: Yeah, your response provide the answer to the actual question. I was just telling the OP that he should update node.

Comment: I am not server admin, can I update node locally in my personal directory? Or should I contact the admin.

Comment: I mean sure you can update it locally for development but if your server is running an old node flavor you'll need it updated there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your `nodejs` version don't understand arrow function, check update if you want use it.

If not, please change arrow function to normal function.

Check [Node.js ES2015 Support](https://node.green/#ES2015-syntax-destructuring--parameters-defaults--arrow-function).